# Change the Activity with another by Intent in mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword method

Tags: java, android, authentication, chat

I try to create this app for my lesson , It sign in successfully but when i try to change the Activity to another one , app crashes. this is my Login method , its in LoginActivity.java and in onCreate() method

```
private void Login(String email, String password) {

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this , new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The value of `task.isSuccessful()` is true , and sign in is successfully , but can`t change the activity.

Comment: share the crash log

Comment: Bro i`m new in android studio . What do you mean ? Do you mean Error log in ```logcat```?

Comment: yes, error log from logcat when crash happens

Comment: @KishanMaurya Thanks you bro i found it on error log ```Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.chat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)``` ... i just removed the ```getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Signin")``` line of ```mainActivity``` and it works ... but do you know what is the problem with this line?

Comment: Share main activity code

Comment: @KishanMaurya ```protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Login");```

Comment: is your app theme is NoActionBar inside res->values->styles.xml or anywhere

Comment: @KishanMaurya yes , in styles , AppTheme is NoActionBar

Comment: then getSupportActionBar will give NULL Pointer Exception, as because no action bar is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your crash logs, 
You are getting NPE on setting an action bar title.
since your theme is No action bar, so it will give NPE.

Just remove below the line, no crash would occur

```
 getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Login");
```

Comment: i want to do it but it shows this message : Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. my reputation is 8.

Comment: No issue. All the best

Comment: Thank you again ... all the best for you too bro.